# What happen to updated system app on Android

Tags: android, system, startup

I've a ROM that comes with a system app included. This system app is a home launcher, and the Android standard launcher has been disabled, so that when when device reboot, this custom launcher is started by default. Then I update that app with a newer version. As far as I know, because this is a system app, an update version of APK will be stored at /data/app/, and the old one in /system/app/ will remain (please correct me if that's not true). And problem is, when device reboot, the app (the newer one, I can check that by adding some specific log) is started up twice (main Activity's onCreate is called twice, the later comes after the previous is destroyed).
In logcat, before my app startup, I found this:

```
01-01 00:00:13.060 I/PackageManager( 3901): Package mypackage at /system/app/MyApp.apk ignored: updated version 21 better than this 18
01-01 00:00:15.670 I/ActivityManager( 3901): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10000000 cmp=mypackage/.MyApp} from pid 0
01-01 00:00:15.670 I/ActivityManager( 3901): start package name is mypackage, class name is mypackage.MyApp, error code is 0
01-01 00:00:15.700 I/ActivityManager( 3901): Start proc mypackage for activity mypackage/.MyApp: pid=4128 uid=1000 gids={41000, 3003, 1028, 1015, 3002, 3001}
...
01-01 00:00:16.170 I/MyApp-Log( 4128): onCreate() called (version 21).
...
01-01 00:00:19.940 D/MyApp-Log( 4128): onDestroy() called
...
01-01 00:00:19.950 I/MyApp-Log( 4128): onCreate() called (version 21).
```

The strange thing is, there will be no problem (that mean app is only started 1 time when reboot) in following cases:

- Do not disable Android default launcher (when reboot, a popup will come to choose which launcher to be started). Choose my custom launcher in this case causes no problem.
- Before installing update version of the custom launcher.
- After install update, reboot device, force-close the launcher and restart it.

Then my question is, what actually happens to a (unique) custom launcher when Android boot up, and does an updated system app cause any difference in the way OS start it up?